# How to clear the cache from `nix-env --query --json --available --file` queries in Nix and NixOS?

Tags: nix, nixos

How can I clear the cache that comes from running `nix-env` queries like so?:

```bash
HASH=a7cc81913bb3cd1ef05ed0ece048b773e1839e51
nix-env --query --json --available \
    --file "https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/archive/${HASH}.tar.gz"
```

Comment: This should be stored in `$HOME/.cache/nix`. You might be able to remove the specific tarball, or just move the entire folder.